# How to cache query result in django?

Tags: python, django, memcached

I am trying to cache query results on my django app. However, it seems that it is caching the whole app. I tried following logi:

```
def cacheView():
  result = cache.get('key')
  if result is None:
    result = Model.objects.get(id=1)
    cache.set('key', 'result')
```

I am calling this method when user logs in. However, if I try to logout after login, it keeps me on same page as if I am still logged in. I tried to follow the Django documentation on cache at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/cache/ but to no success.

Another thing I tried is that if I try to use the cache decorator just above the view as:

```
@cache_control(max_age=1000)
def cacheView():
 ...
```

it does it gives an error saying "response header not defined". I am new to django and sure that I missed something. Any idea?

Answer (score 12):

RTFM :) Official Django Docs: [Caching and QuerySets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets)

> Each QuerySet contains a cache, to minimize database access. (...)

and:

> In a newly created QuerySet, the cache is empty. The first time a QuerySet is evaluated -- and, hence, a database query happens -- Django saves the query results in the QuerySet's cache and returns the results that have been explicitly requested (e.g., the next element, if the QuerySet is being iterated over). Subsequent evaluations of the QuerySet reuse the cached results.

Caching is done automagically in case of QuerySets (results of Queries).

**EDIT:**
As for your code pasted in the question.
If the key doesn't already exist in cache you have to create it with `add()` method but remember that it will expire by default after 30sec. If you want it to be kept longer you have to add timeout option to `add()/set()` method.

If you want to cache for whole your site (to ie. decorators as you used them), you need to add proper middleware to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py (in this exact order, because middleware order matters, it is loaded one by one as you define them):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # ...
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    # ...
)
```

If you don't have them, then you'll be receiving bad header errors every time you'll use caching-per-site capabilities.

Comment: I definitely missed that on the manual. Now that I know it caches the queryset, my next question would be which cache method it uses. Because I wanted to store this in Memcache which I configured in my settings.py but not sure if django will take that method or will use database cache?

Comment: By default django is using local memory to store cache. If you've set other cache backend then django will use it.

Comment: One more question do U need to store this data for a very long time?

Comment: I've read all your question once again and I hope that I didn't misunderstand you. If you need to operate directly on cache with your object look here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api - I think that it will explain all your doubts. I mean caching whole view can be overkill - in some cases you would want to cache only some portion of data and for that you must use django.core.cache package. It's quite easy - you just write to it with set() method and you read from it via get() method. :)

Comment: I am trying to store result  in cache for almost 1 hour.

Comment: I think I am at starting point here again. The URL you suggested now is the same as the one I put in my original question and I have already tried using the set()/add()/get() cache. Using this is causing the whole site to cache somehow. Which is why I can not logout once my cacheView() run. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm using a code very much similar to the one in the `cache_view()` example, having a set line like this: `cache.set(key, value, CACHE_TIMEOUT)`, where CACHE_TIMEOUT is set to 86400. It works as expected, but if I load the page after a couple of minutes, this cache has clearly expired, and it takes the whole value generation time again... why? is there something somewhere that overrides my timeout? does my value contains too many info?

Comment: I don't think the QuerySet cache you're talking about here is related at all to the Django caching backend infrastructure. It is just a python property in the QuerySet object itself that only lasts as long as the object is instantiated (i.e. a single http request). If you want to cache query results for longer you have to write code to use the cache backend explicitly like the original poster was trying to do.

Comment: @Anentropic - read my answer once again, try to unerstand what I'm explaining there. The problem is to get how cache is working and not how to use it in that case. Also question is about setting timeouts and invalidating the cache afterwards, which "poster" do not quite understand I think. Before caching anything there should be a proper strategy and a reason to do this. Also the `QuerySet` object has nothing to do with `cache.set()/cache.add()`. And btw question was edited by the author also after my response - look at the comments..

Comment: @jindals - btw you have an error in your code - using set() like this: `cache.set('key', 'result')` will store a string 'result', if you want to cache result you should use `cache.set('key', result)`.

Comment: how can I know when the queryset is evaluated and when it is reused? for example, let's say I do `qs = model.item_set.all()` and then I do `qs = qs.filter(Q1)`, is the first query set used when evaluating the second? (assuming the first query set is evaluated before filtering, therefore cached, *allegedly*)

Answer (score 1):

From your example it's not clear why the logout would fail, but it shouldn't be anything to do with caching a model (unless you're caching the User model and using the cached user for authentication instead of request.user?)

It's fine to use cache.get and cache.set the way you are (set will create a new key if it doesn't exist).

Caching queries can be difficult as you need to take care of invalidating the cache when data changes so as not to serve stale results.

Have a look at these query-caching libraries for Django which aim to make things easier:

http://jbalogh.me/2010/02/09/cache-machine/

http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/queryset_cache.html

Comment: you don't need additional libs as long as you know what are you doing and what you want to accomplish - there is nothing easier (and more complicated at the same time) than caching.